# How to load Views the lazy way?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm currently building an app with several Views. It's taking a significant time to load. It starts with a white screen and wait for like 5 seconds to load contents. Is there a way to load views one after other after the onCreate is called.This can give a feel that app load faster and become responsive.

If I set all view visibility to GONE and later change each one to VISIBLE inside a handler,is there any benefit?.

Can I make use of ViewStub here?..

Comment: Are you using Android Widget or a custom Views?, 5s is a lot of time, you will face ANR.... Are your making some disk read/write or network job on the UiThread? It's really a best practice to use ViewStub more than view visibility gone if you have a dynamic content, also, make use of RecyclerView if you have many views... UiRendering must always be les than 100ms. Your can activate the strict mode to see if your are doing some work on the UI thread and change it to background thread... Show a loading screen in case your need disk read or network...

Comment: Im using both custom and android views.

Comment: I just tried `AsyncLayoutInflater` and I think its doing something I wanted.. but not exactly. Now App loads completely with main layout and waits for content layout(lots of views here).

Comment: is your main content scrollable? if it is the case you have to use RecyclerView... You have to debug your custom views Draw speed, maybe you could have best performance with some refactor... insure that there is no warning on your customViews... You have to insure that your application meet the strict mode requirement to be sure that your ui still response to user interaction.